# Would a bad main control board in my refrigerator cause inconsistent cooling?

Tags: refrigerator, freezing, freezer

Our Samsung RB215LASH refrigerator has had a persistent intermittent problem with the temperature in the refrigerator section getting too cold, causing stuff to freeze up.  I tried changing the thermistor.

Now I'm seeing it get too cold sometime and see it get too warm sometime.  I'm also seeing the ice thawing in the freezer occasionally.  When it's acting up if I turn it off and on using the breaker, the display will change from showing, say, 48 degrees F when the refrigerator is too cold and will show the correct temperature, say 38 degrees F.

I'm thinking of trying to replace the main board before replacing the whole refrigerator.  Is there anything else that could cause this?  This refrigerator has separate compressors for each section, it doesn't have dampers.

Comment: So long as you're willing to throw away the $180 if that _doesn't_ fix it, I'd go for that option.

Comment: why would you think to replace the main board as the first thing to try? ... it would make more sense to replace it as the last resort ... there is the temperature sensor and the temperature control to check first

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this should be an answer, or a comment, because it's not definitive, but:

Many (all?) bottom freezer fridges have a defrost function.  The evaporator is located in the back of the refrigerator cabinet, usually beind a plastic panel.  The evaporator can build up with frost due to varying temperature and humidity levels.
The fridge is supposed to have a timer that operates a heating coil that is supposed to defrost (melt the frost on) the evaporator.  The defrost function failing can cause the fridge section to overcool.  You may have a problem with the defrost function, but it's hard to say what it might be.

My Samsung had a problem with the defroster drain freezing up, so that when the evaporator was defrosted, the melted water didn't drain and caused an ice rink in the bottom of the cabinet.  I ran some copper wire from the heating element into the drain to extend the melting into the drain.

You may have a similar problem, or your problem may be electrical, such as the defrost timer failing.  Impossible to say without more diagnosis.